# Proving that $(e^x+1)^{1/3}$ has no elementary antiderivative

Tags: integration

How should one prove that $$\int (e^x + 1)^{1/3}\, dx$$ is non-elementary? (In case that is really is)

Comment: Maybe you should explain your interest in this term and also what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

change of variable $$e^x + 1 = u^3, e^x \, dx  = 3u^2 \, du \to dx = \frac{3u^2}{u^3 - 1} du  $$ now we have 
$$\int \left(e^x + 1\right)^{1/3}\, dx  = 3\int \frac{u^3}{u^3 - 1}\, du = 3u + 3\int \frac{du}{(u-1)(u^2 + u+ 1)}$$

the last integral can be done using partial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

```
sage: integrate((exp(x)+1)^(1/3),x)
-sqrt(3)*arctan(1/3*sqrt(3)*(2*(e^x + 1)^(1/3) + 1)) + 3*(e^x + 1)^(1/3) - 1/2*log((e^x + 1)^(2/3) + (e^x + 1)^(1/3) + 1) + log((e^x + 1)^(1/3) - 1)
```

it is elementary...

Comment: Is Sage really necessary? First $x = \log(y)$, then $y = z^3 - 1$, and then it's a rational function of $z$ (which admittedly is painful to do by hand, but the question was whether it is integrable in elementary terms, not to find an anti-derivative).

Comment: well, consider my answer being done by computer, not me :-)

Comment: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1700/is-it-frowned-upon-to-answer-a-question-and-vote-to-close